# Testing Controllers that are within Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

I'm using Rspec and I want to test a controller that is within a module that is within another module.

```
module Food
  module Fruit
    class ApplesController < ApplicationController

    etc...
```

I currently have my rspec file `apples_controller_spec.rb` looking like

```
require 'spec_helper'

  describe ApplesController do

  etc..
```

What is the naming convention for Rspec in regards to testing a controller that is within two modules because currently I'm getting an error that `uninitialized constant BurstsController (NameError)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
require 'spec_helper'
module Food
  module Fruit
    describe ApplesController do
```

or you could do:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Food::Fruit::ApplesController do
```

personally I use the former.

Comment: Ahh. I tried the latter before asking the question. and it didn't work. Realized that I overcapitalized the module name. Did it again and it's working!! Thanks for the other option as well.